# Modified AngularJS Script ASP.NET Bundled old Script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

So I have my `angular.js` script in my script folder. I added some code to it and I expect the ASP NET bundler to bundle that version and use it.

When I deployed to production, I'm getting an error saying that some properties don't exists. These properties reside in the `angular.js` file. The production is using minified code and I copied that code into a text editor and performed a search for my properties and it didn't find them.

I added this:

```
child.myProperty = "Some property";
```

So minified should look something like:

```
c.myProperty="Some Property";
```

I'm pointing to the correct file because in DEV it works fine. It's just something in the bundling process is using an old file or something.

My bundle is this:

```
ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
    "~/Scripts/angular.js",
    "~/Scripts/angular-ui-router.js",
    "~/Scripts/angular-resource.js",
    "~/Scripts/angular-local-storage.js");
```

I have this property set in the web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
```

What is the most likely cause for this error?

Comment: Without more details of what exactly is breaking or which file is not being loading I'm not sure how we can help you out. Its likely an injection issue and some file is not using minify safe DI (use $static or the array syntax)

Comment: I said, it is angular js file.

Comment: which angular js file?

Comment: the angular.js file, the one, the only one. the angular.js script file that you get when you download angular

Comment: You were vague about the file, thanks for the edit. Why not use their minified version? Just include `angular.min.js` instead